# What is Bane's ethnicity in The Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: dc, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

In the *Knightfall* series of comics, Bane is a Central American of a possibly mixed ethnicity (see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12999/40294)).

In *The Dark Knight Rises*, it is more ambiguous — Alfred, having researched Bane, mentions that Bane spent time in a prison in an "older part of the world".

Bane himself speaks English in a roughly English accent, albeit muffled.

[image]

**In the Nolan trilogy, what is Bane's ethnicity?**

Are there any authoritative statements on this?

Note: The location of the prison may be significant in arriving at an answer, but the location alone is not enough to form a conclusion.

Comment: Related: [What nationality is Bane?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3814/49) (and to some degree: [What is the geographic location of the pit Bruce Wayne is imprisoned in by Bane?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3454/49))

Comment: If his voice is any indication, it's [Disneyan](http://lionking.wikia.com/wiki/Rafiki)

Comment: I think there are very few accents in movies - Hispanic (la Bamba), British, French, German, then everything else gets lumped into Middle Eastern, sub-Saharan African, Asian, Rasta, or Transylvanian.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to statements by Tom Hardy, [reported by MTV](http://www.mtv.com/news/1689960/dark-knight-rises-bane-tom-hardy/), his version of Bane was intended to be of [Romani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people) heritage:

> "There's the history of [Bane] being Latino and speaking Spanish and all the stuff like that, so I went for Romani Gypsy instead of Latin, but I went lateral myself," [Hardy] said. "If that upsets people ... I hope it doesn't. There were a lot of conscious choices made around him to benefit both the fans and new people."

This mildly conflicts with other statements made by Hardy, particularly that [he based Bane's accent](http://www.vulture.com/2012/07/tom-hardy-explains-his-bane-voice-inspiration.html) on [Bartley Gorman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartley_Gorman), a Welsh-Irish bare-knuckle boxer:

> "It's based on a guy named Bartley Gorman," [Hardy] told us. *[...]* "He's the king of the gypsies, and he's a boxer, a bare-knuckle boxer, an Irish traveler, a gypsy."

As Hardy notes, Gorman was an [Irish Traveller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_Travellers), not a Romani gypsy; a relation between the two is not impossible, but is [disputed](http://scholarlycommons.law.wlu.edu/crsj/vol11/iss1/4/).

The Romani origin is more consistent with Bane's incarceration; although the exact location of the prison is unknown, it's [presumed to be in North Africa](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3454), and is clearly *not* in the British Isles, where the Irish Travellers primarily reside.